# How to use optional query parameters in Yada?

Tags: clojure, yada

I'm making a toy API using the Yada library in Clojure. It searches a database for city names starting with the given characters and returns some info about it.

I want a URI of the form: `/cities/:name?count=:count` so for example `/cities/ber?count=4` will return the top 4 matches. But I also want `/cities/ber` without the `?count=` parameter to return a default number of results (say just the first).

I've defined my route and yada handler like this:

```clj
(defn city-search-fn
  [ctx]
  (let [name (get-in ctx [:parameters :path :name])
        count (get-in ctx [:parameters :query :count] 1)]
    (city->geoposition name count)))

(def cities (yada/handler (yada/resource 
                            {:methods 
                             {:get
                              {:parameters {:path {:name String}
                                            :query {:count Long}}
                               :produces ["application/json"
                                          "application/edn"]
                               :response city-search-fn}}})))

(def routes
  [["/cities/" :name] cities])

(def server
  (yada/listener routes {:port 30000}))
```

This works fine if I supply the `?count=` query parameter:

```sh
$ curl -i 'http://localhost:30000/cities/ber?count=2'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 259
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: accept
Server: Aleph/0.4.4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 16:01:45 GMT

[{"name":"Berlin","state":"Berlin","countrycode":"DE","timezone":"Europe/Berlin","latitude":52.52437,"longitude":13.41053},{"name":"Berbera","state":"Woqooyi Galbeed","countrycode":"SO","timezone":"Africa/Mogadishu","latitude":10.43959,"longitude":45.01432}]
```

But I get status 400 (`{:status 400, :errors ([:query {:error {:count missing-required-key}}])}`) if I don't supply it:

```sh
$ curl -i 'http://localhost:30000/cities/ber'
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 77
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Server: Aleph/0.4.4
Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 16:06:56 GMT



{:status 400, :errors ([:query {:error {:count missing-required-key}}])}
```

The documentation of yada says it supports optional query parameters using the "schema" library. So I found in schema's documentation that there exists a `schema.core/maybe` function. I tried to modify my yada resource as follows:

```clj
:parameters {:path.....
             :query (schema/maybe {:count Long})}
```

this doesn't work (same 400 error).

Then I tried:

```clj
:parameters {:path.....
             :query {:count  (schema/maybe Long)}}
```

this also didn't work.

So my question is: what is the correct way to have an optional query parameter in yada?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, digging more into Schema documentation, here is the correct way:

```clj
:parameters {:path.....
             :query {(schema/optional-key :count) Long}}
```

The key itself needs to be marked as optional.